# ANTLR3: compiling warning(200) "multiple alternatives"

Tags: compiler-warnings, antlr3

I'm using antlrworks1.5 with antlr3 and encountered the following warning/error. I have been working on this issue for a couple of days, could anybody give me some hint? Thank you in advance.

The minimized grammar file is:

```
grammar p;

cs : '[' c ']';
c  : 'x' ('p' c)*;
```

AntLR reports the following warning: warning(200):Decision can match input such as "'p'" using multiple alternatives:1,2

ttp://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7cQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnRvx.png

I am wondering:
(1) what is the meaning of 'matched using multiple alternatives"? does it means that the grammar is ambiguous? If it is, could you please give me some example?
(2) how to solve this problem in general?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar is indeed ambiguous. To understand this, replace the Kleene star by transforming to plain BNF:

```
c ::= 'x' 
    | c 'p' c
```

Now this is both left- and right-recursive, so derivations can build subtrees on either side, thus creating different parse trees for the same words.

Directly from the EBNF, this is slighly harder to see. Here the difference manifests itself in parse trees differing in depth, depending on whether the repetition is used or not:

```
       c                 c                           
      /|                /|\             
     / |               | | \
    / /|\              | |  \
   / / | \     vs.     | |   c           
  / /| | |             | |  /|\         
 | / c | c             | | | | c        
 | | | | |             | | | | |  
 x p x p x             x p x p x
```

ANTLR's perspective on this is determined by the SLL algorithm. When processing the repetition, it must be decided whether to 
proceed with another iteration, or complete the right hand side of the `c` production. In either case, a lookahead
token from the followers of `c` is expected - in the first case, because `c` is at the very end of the repeated part, 
in the second case because the repetition occurs at the end of the `c` production. Thus the inability to decide.

The solution is fairly obvious: make sure that there is one unique way to obtain a repeated sequence. In this case, either omit the recursion by just having `c : 'x' ('p' 'x')*;`, or replace the Kleene star by an option, `c : 'x' ('p' c)?;`.